# writing to disk: File access denied

Tags: c#, file-io

I try to write my data to an Excel file. I'm using workbook method SaveAs. This is the code:

```
string FN = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\dane1.xlsx";
WB.SaveAs(FN, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
            Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
            Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared,
            Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
            Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
```

Everything is OK while the first parameter is hardcoded. When I try use a reference to object where I'm keeping path and file name (I've got it from SaveFileDialog) my application return me an exception:

> File access denied".

What's wrong? Does anybody know how this can be avoided?

Comment: Looks like the file is open already (your app has it open for modification).

Answer (score 2):

IF you're running Vista / Windows 7 you may need to run your application as Administrator to save to `c:\Users\Documents` (which generally doesn't exist)

Did you mean `c:\Users\'username'\Documents`?

in C# you could use
`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("userprofile")` to get the users folder (ie c:\Users\Postman) - which is like type %userprofile% into run.